# Zend Framework Bootstrap Issue

Tags: zend-framework, init, bootstrapping

I have been working on a new installation of a Zend Framework application for a while now, and I cannot figure out what's going on.  I have two custom action helpers I would like to use and I would like to initialize those in the bootstrap.  But it seems as though my _init functions are not being called at all.  In the index.php that starts the application I have:

```
require('Zend/Application.php');

$app = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH 
.'/configs/application.ini');

$app->bootstrap()->run();
```

Here's what I have in the application.ini file:

```
[production]

appnamespace = "Application_Name"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

bootstrap.path = "/home/user/website/includes/library/Application_Name/Resource/Bootstrap.php"

bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

resources.view[] =

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Application_Name"

pluginPaths.Application_Name_Resource = "Application_Name/Resource"
```

I know the application is somewhat working because it is using a layout that I have and I can do things in the controllers and views and have it output to the page.  I also know that it is at least looking at the Bootstrap file because I can make a PHP error happen when I leave out an end curly brace.

Here's a portion of my Bootstrap file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

        public function _init()
        {
                Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix(new Application_Name_Controller_Action_Helper_ResourceInjector());
                Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix(new Application_Name_Controller_Action_Helper_Em());
        }
```

Any ideas why this would be or see something that I've messed up in my configuration?  I've looked at tens of tutorials on how to configure Zend, and no one else seems to have this problem.

Comment: The default `Bootstrap.php` location is `APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"`. Any reason you've changed that?

Comment: Not really.  I just put it in the library.  I can put it back, but I don't think it will change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the helper broker correctly. `addPrefix()` is used to add pluginloader prefix paths, not actual classes.

If you want to add concrete helpers (to use their dispatch hooks presumably), then place something like this in your Bootstrap class

```
protected function _initActionHelpers()
{
    $helper = new My_Helper;
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($helper);
}
```

For regular, runtime helpers, you can easily add prefix paths in your config, eg

```
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.ProEquipTrack_Controller_Action_Helper = "ProEquipTrack/Controller/Action/Helper"
```

These will be automatically loaded by the broker at call time, eg (controller context)

```
$resourceInjector = $this->getHelper('ResourceInjector');
$em = $this->getHelper('Em');
```

or using the strategy pattern (`direct()` method)

```
$this->_helper->resourceInjector($arg1, $arg2 /*, etc */);
```

---

### Doctrine Entity Manager

Do something like this in your Bootstrap class

```
protected function _initDoctrine()
{
    // initialise and create entity manager
    $em = // whatever

    return $em;
}
```

You can now access the entity manager in your controllers using this

```
$em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')
           ->getResource('doctrine');
```

Comment: How then do I I call Em.php or is it loaded for me?

Comment: So those _init functions are being called but you can't die inside them... hmm.  Thanks!

Comment: @Phil is there a way to pass something to the controller from the bootstrap?

Comment: @tubaguy Such as? You can access app resources using `$res = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('resource_name')`

Comment: @Phil Doctrine entity manager?  I initialize doctrine in my bootstrap and I would like to allow access to the em object in the controller by calling $this->em to run queries and such.