# How to use a custom Zend Framework form in a directory inside application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a "forms" directory inside my application directory with custom form php files in there.  In my application.ini the appnamespace is "Application".  The form name I'm trying to use is BetaSignup.php.  The class is Application_Form_BetaSignup.

In my controller I try to do `$form = new Application_Form_BetaSignup`, and I get an error saying:

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_BetaSignup' not found.

Thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the typical `application/forms` directory for your form classes if you name them appropriately using the configured `appnamespace` directive (default "Application"). Please note, the directory name is lowercase "forms".

For example, say you have a registration form "Registration". Create the file at `application/forms/Registration.php` (note the case sensitivity) containing the class

```
class Application_Form_Registration extends Zend_Form
{
    // etc
```

The resource autoloader will be able to find your form when you instantiate it in your controllers, eg

```
$form = new Application_Form_Registration(); // will be auto-loaded
```

Comment: Can I have a form name that is camel cased two words such as Application_Form_BetaSignup ?

Comment: @tubaguy Yes, just name the file the same as the last part, ie `BetaSignup.php`

Comment: I updated with your changes and I'm getting an error.  I updated my question with the new information.

Comment: @tubaguy Did you move your `Bootstrap.php` file back to the `application` directory? The location of this file defines the resource loader root. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/q/6247605/283366

Comment: Nope.  Did now and it's all better!